# How do I configure mst-gql to work with react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx-react, gql, mobx-state-tree

I have been trying hard to configure mst-gql to work with react-native. I have tried it like I would generally with ReactJS. It doesn't work. Is there something else I need to do?

```js
/**
 * @format
 */
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import RootComponent from './src/App';
import {createHttpClient} from 'mst-gql';
import {RootStore, StoreContext} from './src/models';

const rootStore = RootStore.create(undefined, {
  gqlHttpClient: createHttpClient('http://localhost:8000/graphql'),
});

const App = () => (
  <StoreContext.Provider value={rootStore}>
    <RootComponent />
  </StoreContext.Provider>
);

// @ts-ignore
window.store = rootStore;

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly does not work? Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I changed the 'localhost:port' to 'machineip:port' (192.168.1.35:8000) while  creating gqlHttpClient.